# SSRS report optimization : dataset do's and dont's

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My company just landed a substantial customer, for which I'll need to optimize the reports I'll be creating.

After some reading on the internet, below are the few things that should be avoided and should be seen as best pratices.

> Should be avoided

- Not use conditional queries `CASE`
- Small queries with one to two tables in case of a `join`
- Don‘t retrieve any unnecessary data

> Best pratices

- Use indexed columns
- Only subset of data based on a drilldown path (e.g. Time = 2008 Q2, Product = Bikes)

Questions are the following:

- If `CASE` sql should be avoided , should I use `IIF` instead? If yes, why?
- Are there any available time metrics for let's say 10 000 records involved when using a `CASE` in the dataset and when using the `IIF`?
- Should I put every data in a single big dataset with many columns like this

  > `dataset1= SELECT col1,col2,CASE WHEN col3 = 'X' THEN 'yes I can' ELSE 'no' END AS col3 FROM x`

  Or should I break them into pieces?

  > `dataset1 = 'SELECT col1,col2 FROM x'`
  >
  > `dataset2 ='SELECT CASE WHEN col3 = 'X' THEN 'yes I can' ELSE 'no' END AS col3 FROM x'`

Many thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Only advice i can confirm. Make sure your queries run fast server side(optimize, be sure you are using the correct indexes, this is a broad topic) and keep your Datasets as small as possible. Never had problems with CASE or "small queries".

Comment: One big performance improvement is to use any parameters in the query and **not** filtering them on the dataset (the **FILTER** tab). This will let the server perform the calculation for the filter and only return the data that is needed rather than returning extra data and making the report server do the work.